# How to create a dynamic message with Protocol Buffers?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Say we want to create our message not using any preexisting .proto files and compiled out from them cpp/cxx/h files. We want to use protobuf strictly as a library. For example we got (in some only known to us format) message description: a message called `MyMessage` has to have `MyIntFiels` and optional `MyStringFiels`. How to create such message? for example fill it with simple data save to `.bin` and read from that binary its contents back?

I looked all over [dynamic_message.h help description](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.dynamic_message) and DescriptorPool and so on but do not see how to add/remove fields to the message as well as no way to add described on fly message to DescriptorPool.

Can any one please explain?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it can't be used that way.

The [overview page](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) of Protobuf says:

> XML is also – to some extent – self-describing. A protocol buffer is only meaningful if you have the message definition (the .proto file).

Meaning the whole point of Protobuf is to throw-out self-descriptability in favor of parsing speed ==> it's just not it's purpose to create self describing messages.

Consider using XML or JSON or any other serialization format. If the protection is needed, you can use symmetric encryption and/or lzip compression.

Comment: Not true. [dynamic_message.h](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.dynamic_message) `Defines an implementation of Message which can emulate types which are not known at compile-time.`

Comment: Problem is, if I understand the documentation correctly, it is used for dynamic parsing of messages, not dynamic message creation. See [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description): "By using classes like DynamicMessage (available in C++ and Java), you can then write tools which can manipulate SelfDescribingMessage". I wasn't totally correct about self-description possibility, I admit, but the advice holds.

Comment: We can generate on fly file like `message MyMessage {int32 MyIntFiels = 1; string MyStringFiels = 2;}` how to feed such string to it?

Comment: why don't you just send the same as JSON? By putting this into protobuf message format along with the headers, you won't win anything.

Comment: See protobuf support in version 5.5+ of Confluent Schema registry